# Can't install GCC in Ubuntu 20.04 WSL

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, windows-subsystem-for-linux, apt, dpkg

I have tried to install gcc in Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL :

`apt -y install gcc` return error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 194 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up gcc (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gcc doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package gcc (--configure):
 installed gcc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gcc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to fix it with :

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends gcc 
sudo apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get autoclean -y
sudo apt-get clean gcc
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

But then I got error :

```
    root@LAP123:/home/my_user# sudo apt-get install gcc
   .......
Setting up desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/desktop-file-utils.postinst: 5: update-desktop-database: not found
    dpkg: error processing package desktop-file-utils (--configure):
     installed desktop-file-utils package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
    Setting up gcc (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
    update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gcc doesn't exist
    dpkg: error processing package gcc (--configure):
     installed gcc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     desktop-file-utils
     gcc
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I install gcc in my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install GCC with ***sudo apt install gcc***

if that doesn't work try upgrading your packages.

I found the YouTube video at https://www.systranbox.com/how-to-install-gcc-on-wsl-linux/ somewhat helpful in that regard.